# Unable to resolve absolute url() paths for background images in CSS with Webpack

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, urlloader, webpack-style-loader

I have the following Webpack config (roughly, it has been simplified for this post):

```
const rootPublic = path.resolve('./public');
const LOCAL_IDENT_NAME = 'localIdentName=[name]_[local]_[hash:base64:5]';
const CSS_LOADER = `css?sourceMap&${LOCAL_IDENT_NAME}&root=${rootPublic}`;
const SASS_LOADER = 'sass?sourceMap&includePaths[]=' + path.resolve(__dirname, './src/styles');

// ... loaders:

loaders: [
  {
    test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/,
    loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&name=[path][name].[ext]'
  },
  {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    loader: config.DEVELOPMENT_MODE ? `style!${CSS_LOADER}!autoprefixer!${SASS_LOADER}`
                : ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', `${CSS_LOADER}!autoprefixer!${SASS_LOADER}`)
  }, // ...
]
```

Now this works perfectly fine for images referenced normally in scss files:

```
.some-static-class {
  background: url('/images/bg.png');
}
```

However, it does *not* work when using the `:local` directive:

```
:local .SomeClass {
  background: url('/images/bg.png');
}
```

And I think that's because `root` is defined for the CSS loader. I get a build error: `Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./../../../../../../../../images/bg.gif`

If instead I remove `root` from the css-loader config, then it builds fine but then the path "looks" correct in Chrome's inspector, but when you actually open the link in a new tab, it points to: `chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/"/images/bg.png"` which obviously doesn't resolve correctly.

I'm not sure if the problem is with the `url-loader` config, or what's going on exactly.

I played around with different webpack configs to specify the resolve.root, resolve.modulesDirectories, etc but totally not sure if they're having any affect or if I'm just going about it completely wrong. I also came across `resolve-url-loader` but not sure if that's even what I need at all.

Any ideas? MTIA!

**UPDATE**

I should note, that it works fine in Safari, but not in Chrome. So it seems like a Chrome-specific bug, but it's not practical to have to do all our development in Safari.

I also came across, [vue-style-loader](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-style-loader), which is a fork of style-loader that claims to fix this issue, but the way it fixes it is by relying on a hacky deprecated escape/unescape method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible solution that I could come up with was the following:

Use `resolve-url-loader` (immediately after `sass-loader`):

```
style!${CSS_LOADER}!autoprefixer!resolve-url!${SASS_LOADER}
```

Then, define a resolve.alias for static images:

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    images: path.join(__dirname, 'public/images')
  }
}
```

And then in the CSS, you can point to the images like so:

```
:local .SomeClass {
  background: url('images/bg.png');
}
```

Depending on your URL structure, you may also need to tweak the `url-loader` name param:

```
{
  test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/,
  loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&name=images/[name].[ext]'
}
```

---

So I don't know if there's a cleaner way to solve this issue, but that's the best I could come up with so far. I'd welcome any feedback or alternatives.

Thanks!

**UPDATE 6/30/2016**

There's a couple PR's out that would address this issue, but the maintainer prefers the solution to be in the CSS AST rather than in the CSS loader...

https://github.com/webpack/style-loader/pull/124
https://github.com/webpack/style-loader/pull/96

Here's hoping a real fix happens soon...

Answer (score 2):

With webpack 2:

In your .scss files use ~ before the path.

```
.yourClass {
      background: url('~img/wallpaper.png');
}
```

Make use of the resolve root from webpack, add this to your webpack.config.js:

```
resolve: {
        modules: [
            path.resolve(root),
            'node_modules'
        ]
    },
```

It should work also for the @import, eg @import "~otherfile.scss"