# image url/path to use with webpack in css?

Tags: webpack

I'm working on a project with react and webpack. I'm using the url loader plugin for images. This works fine if I want to include the image in an img tag. But I want to include an image in my css as a background image. ie

```
const hero = require('../../images/landing-hero.jpg');
```

this returns a filename which works fine everywhere except in my css.

```
.hero {
  background-image: url('3b1425242c422b429f78f272b0a4c0f7.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  min-height: 101vh;
  color: white;
}
```

I've tried a few variations of the path with no success. doing http://localhost:8080/3b1425242c422b429f78f272b0a4c0f7.jpg works however. How can I use the image as a background url without doing the entire url? 
This is my webpack config

```
'use strict';

/*=============================================>>>>>
= MODULES =
===============================================>>>>>*/

const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const WebpackNotifier = require('webpack-notifier');
// PostCSS
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

'use strict';

/*=============================================>>>>>
= MODULES =
===============================================>>>>>*/

const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const WebpackNotifier = require('webpack-notifier');
// PostCSS
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

/*= End of MODULES =*/
/*=============================================<<<<<*/

/*=============================================>>>>>
= WEBPACK CONFIG =
===============================================>>>>>*/

module.exports = {
  entry:   {
    app: path.resolve(`${__dirname}/src/client/public/app/main.tsx`)
  },
  output: {
    path:     path.resolve(`${__dirname}/build/client`),
    filename: 'public/zip/[name].bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.tsx$/, loader: 'babel!ts' },
      { test: /\.scss$/, loader: 'style!css?sourceMap!postcss!sass?sourceMap' },
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style!css?sourceMap!postcss'},
      { test: /\.(png|jpg)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192'}
    ]
  },
  postcss: function() {
    return [ autoprefixer ];
  },
  ts: {
    silent: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new WebpackNotifier({ title: 'Webpack', alwaysNotify: true }),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
  ]
};

/*= End of WEBPACK CONFIG =*/
/*=============================================<<<<<*/
```

I've tried the solution offered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35786100/unable-to-resolve-absolute-url-paths-for-background-images-in-css-with-webpack) with resolve-url-loader but I don't think I put the resolve-url in the right spot in my loader since mine is slightly different than theirs. New to webpack and I've looked at other similar questions with no luck so sorry if this feels like its been asked

Comment: Maybe use the file loader instead of the url loader? According to https://github.com/webpack/css-loader, everything should work out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/webpack/css-loader/issues/29), when the `sourcemap` is enabled, it will using the blob to serve the css on your page. Which will cause the problem because the background `url()` is relative to the css, therefore in the blob it couldn't find the file, thus not rendering the image.

It has few ways to resolve this issue:

1. use the `DataUrl`, see the [url-loader](https://github.com/webpack/url-loader), set the `limit` accordingly
2. if your image file is big and you don't wish to use the data url, you can set the `output.publicPath` to your URL. For example usually in the local development mode, `http://localhost:3000/`. However this workaround is not perfect especially when you have HTTPS implementation. Still you can write some simple code to tweak this value accordingly.